# Audio Not Playing When Switching to Other App

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have this Xaml code :

```
<MediaElement x:Name="Player" Visibility="Collapsed" 
   AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" />
```

When I run it on my `Desktop`, the audio still played when I `minimize` app.
But on `Windows Mobile 10 Emulator`, the audio stops playing when I switch to other app.

Is this by design or there's some other setting to enable same behaviour on `Windows Mobile 10` ?

Comment: I've tested your code in Windows 10, version 1511, OS Build 10586.36, but I can't reproduce your problem. And the audio should not play when the app is minimized, because when the app is minimized, it is suspended.

Comment: My Windows is build 10586 too, and for my app I'm targetting 10586 in project setting (after I upgrade my VS to 2015 Update 1, I cannot target 10240 anymore).

Comment: @AskTooMuch I am also having this issue. Did you get a solution for it?

Comment: @ac-lab Unfortunately, I still haven't got solution for this issue, and I have pending my audio player project and move on to other project until this issue "solved", :(

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to reproduce this issue on my desktop. When I minimize the app, the background audio stops playing.

This is an expected behavior, when you minimize an UWP app, switch to desktop or another app, the foreground process, which contains UI and client logic, will be suspended. This being said, the foreground media player will be suspended too.

With UWP app, you can use the **BackgroundMediaPlayer** to play the background audio. Essentially, the media player will be played in the background process instead of the foreground, and it continues running even when the foreground process is suspended.

For more details, you can see to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt282140.aspx

You can also find some sample code in https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundAudio